# How to run java class file from C inside a Maven project

Tags: java, c, maven, java-native-interface, beagleboard

I do have a WebApp (WAR file) in a Maven project running fine.

I want to call a Java method in a class file which is inside the maven project from a C file. The C program reads the GPIO input of my beagleboard and when it's on, it runs the Java method. I use JNI for doing that.

I can run a classic HelloWorld Java method, but when I want to run a method from my Maven project, I got a fatal error from my JVM when its trying to load the Java static method.

I added the C code in my WebApp, in /WEB-INF/myapp/classes/classfile/

Class file : App
Method : test

my C program:

```
JNIEnv* create_vm(JavaVM ** jvm) {

    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options;
    //Path to the java source code
    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./";
    //JDK version. This indicates version 1.6
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if(ret < 0)
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM\n");
    return env;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd, ret, data[64];
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM * jvm;
    env = create_vm(&jvm);
    if (env == NULL)
        return 1;

    fd = ret = open(argv[argc - 1], O_RDONLY);
    printf("open returned %d\n", ret);
    while (1) {
        ret = read(fd, &data, sizeof(data));
        printf("read returned %d\n", ret);
        jclass helloWorldClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "App");
        printf("appel class\n");
        jmethodID mainMethod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(
            env, helloWorldClass, "test", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        printf("appel method\n");
        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, helloWorldClass, mainMethod, NULL);

        sleep(2);
    }
    (*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
    exit(0);
}
```

Java class :

```
package App;
public class App 
{
   public static void test (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 for beagleboard - you should add that tag, btw.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you investigated using [Reverse JNI](http://java.sys-con.com/node/45840)?</strike>

I notice that you have the following line:

`options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=./"; //Path to the java source code`

The classpath needs to point to either the jar file generated by Maven, or the root directory under which your Java class files are located.

See:  [Setting the ClassPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html),

In a standard Maven project, Maven will create your jar under `target/` when you execute `mvn package`. So you'll likely change `-Djava.class.path=./` to `-cp /target/App.jar`

Comment: Reverse JNI is what I use. But I can't run a java App which is in a Maven project :/